# How to install KDE on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, kde

At my work we had to install a Linux distribution to replace Windows XP. We liked KDE but we only had to use CDs. So we chose Lubuntu and now we want KDE. Is there any way we can install KDE. Will it erase any applications that have been installed (LibreOffice, VirtualBox,Code::Blocks IDE, and Filezilla). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - install the personal package Archive

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
```

2 - wich one

if you want kubuntu-full 'the kubuntu-fll contains a full Kubuntu installation (kubuntu running kde)'

```
$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

if you want kde-full contains most KDE modules including everything in kde-plasma-desktop

```
$ sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

and if you want only the kde-plasma-desktop contains the bare minimum for KDE Plasma workspace

```
$ sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

source : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE

Comment: There is no need to use a ppa. I advise kubuntu-desktop to new users. the other options, IMO, are for more advanced users.

Comment: I will be trying the kde-full, we don't need the extra add-ons that Kubuntu has. I didn't vote up because my reputation is too low.

Comment: If this doesn't work we still have all of the Lubuntu install CDs that we made.

Comment: you can also remove them 
by $ sudo apt-get purge kde-full or the kde-plasma desktop just change the kde-full or sudo apt-get autoremove kde-full

Comment: I am stuck at the login box and will reinstall because it didn't work.