# Removing lubuntu or LXDE

Tags: 15.04, lubuntu, kubuntu, kde, lxde

I've just installed kde-desktop, according to this tutorial:
[How to install KDE on Lubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491853/how-to-install-kde-on-lubuntu-14-04)

Now I have both lubuntu(LXDE) and kubuntu(KDE) and want to remove lubuntu, can I do it?

Also, on startup screen, I have a choice to run Lubuntu, Lubuntu netbook, Plasma(Which I loved), failsafe and openbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(lubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(kubuntu-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(lxde),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(kubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

This removes the installed packages that reverse-depend on lubuntu and not those for kubuntu-desktop.